# Missing Required Gems - javan-whenever and cron job in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, cron, whenever

I have finally managed to get javan-whenever gem working on my site5 server, and updating the crontab is quite easy, however whenever a cron job is run with the code that is generated, i get a "missing required gems" error where it lists about 8/10 of my gems.

Has anyone else had this problem? If so, what would the solution be.

The funny thing is that when it outputs where my gems are, this is all correct, and the gems are loading fine from within my application.

Cheers,
Matenia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed to get this working via creating `script/CUSTOMscript` files and running the cron job through there .. would be glad to show someone if theyre having the same problem.

Comment: Yes, please!  I'm having an issue where my gems aren't being found when running rake db:migrate through capistrano.

Comment: the script/yourscriptname should contain the following:
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/environment'
#rake 'sendnewsletter'
require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rake/rdoctask'
require 'tasks/rails'
Rake::Task['sendnewsletter'].invoke

then this invokes my custom rake task which is called :sendnewsletter.

Then I set up the cron job in the cpanel backend to run the script every week. its a bit cumbersome, but it works. and I don't have that many custom rake tasks to worry about so it's manageable.